# Conditional union and edit rows as columns

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, aggregate, union

I always be impressed on what I found so far on this site. This time it is my turn to have a question...

I have the following tables :

Appt :

| ApptId | ResourceId |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | abcde |
| 12345 | bcdef |
| 23456 | defgh |
| 34567 | cdefg |

Resource:

| ResourceId | ResourceType |
| --- | --- |
| abcde | Person |
| bcdef | Place |
| cdefg | Place |
| defgh | Person |

Place :

| PlaceId | ResourceId | PlaceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zzzzz | bcdef | Boston |
| yyyyy | cdefg | Dallas |

Person:

| PersonId | ResourceId | PersonName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wwwww | abcde | Smith |
| xxxxx | defgh | Doe |

and I try to have this :

| ApptId | ResourceName | PlaceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Smith | Boston |
| 23456 | Doe |  |
| 34567 |  | Dallas |

So for the moment I am able to have this :

| ApptId | ResourceName | PlaceName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Smith |  |
| 12345 |  | Boston |
| 23456 | Doe |  |
| 34567 |  | Dallas |

But I failed to aggregate Resource and Place if they are about the same Appointment.

Hope this is clear

Comment: Sounds like a case for unpivot for me...

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to have SELECT statement with two left outer joins, as follows:

```
SELECT Appt.ApptId, Person.PersonName, Place.PlaceName
FROM Appt
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person ON Appt.ResourceId = Person.ResourceId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Place ON Appt.ResourceId = Place.ResourceId
```

Comment: Yes indeed one detail is still anoying, we can have multiple Persons related to one ApptId so we just neeed the first occurence, where may I put the top 1 ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by first occurrence. If you mean the one with the lowest value, then you can use the MIN and GROUP BY functions.